# Typescript - Execute code in files without importing them

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way I can run the code in files without importing them in TypeScript (Angular project)? Maybe by specifying a file pattern through some config in tsconfig?

What I'd like to do is register some classes into a global object, but I don't want to maintain the list of classes in a single file. I'd rather have a simple line of code under each class definition like so:

```
export class MyClassToRegister {...}

GlobalRegistry.register(MyClassToRegister);
```

I understand this code will get executed when the file gets imported, but sometimes that's just too late. Any on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Are you using Webpack to bundle/build your TypeScript project?

Comment: Yes I am. It's a basic Angualr 5 project

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using Webpack's [`require.context(...)`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-context) you can import a directory of files into your bundle.

Quick note: you're still importing the files into the bundle, but you just don't have to statically define every import path or manually have to keep them up-to-date if you add/remove files.

#### File structure:

Let's work with this example file structure:

```
src/
    items/
        item1.ts
        item2.ts
        item3.ts
    registry.ts
    index.ts
```

Here are the items we're going to require from a directory:

```
//item1.ts, item2.ts, item3.ts
import GlobalRegistry from "../registry";

export class Item1 {
    //...
}
GlobalRegistry.register(Item1);
```

The loaded items will register themselves with this service (or whatever your business logic is) - this proves that the items are being loaded:

```
//registry.ts
export default class GlobalRegistry {

    static _items = [];

    static register(cls){
        console.log('Register class: ', cls.name);
        this._items.push(cls.name);
    }

    static getItems(){
        return this._items;
    }

}
```

#### require.context(...)

Use `require.context(...)` to require all files under the 'items' directory:

```
//index.ts
import GlobalRegistry from './registry';

// Import all files under './items/*.ts'
var context = require.context('./items', true, /\.ts$/);
context.keys().forEach((key) => {
    context(key);
});

console.log('Loaded classes:', GlobalRegistry.getItems());
```

Finally, to keep TypeScript happy we declare the `require.context()` interface provided by Webpack:

```
//references.d.ts

// Extend @types/node NodeRequire type to define Webpack's context function
declare interface NodeRequire {
    context: (dir: string, includeSubdirs: boolean, filter: RegExp) => any;
}

// Tell TypeScript that there is a global `require` variable available to us
declare var require: NodeRequire;
```

#### Result:

When the application runs you should see this logged out:

```
Register class:  Item1
Register class:  Item2
Register class:  Item3
Loaded classes: (3) ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
```

---

### Notes:

**1. Order of includes**
The order of includes is not guaranteed if you reference individual classes first.

For example, if you explicitly import a type **and use it as a value** then that type will be loaded before others that are only included via `require.context(...)`.

Example - using Item2 as a value:

```
//index.ts

/* require.context(...) stuff is here */

import {Item2} from './items/Item2';
let myItem = new Item2();   // use Item2 as a value
```

Changes the load order:

```
Register class:  Item2
Register class:  Item1
Register class:  Item3
Loaded classes: (3) ["Item2", "Item1", "Item3"]
```

But note that just referencing by type (and not by value) will not change the load order

```
let myItem: Item2;  // just referencing by type won't affect load order
```

**2. Require function dependencies warning**

You might get a warning during build like: `require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`.

There isn't necessarily anything *wrong* with that, it's just Webpack letting you know that you're doing something funky with `require` - which is true :)

Doing this dynamic require might affect tree-shaking or other static analysis of your bundle (i.e. those types can't be excluded from the bundle if they're not used). But it might be a fair trade-off by not having to manually manage your file imports - you'll have to evaluate against your own requirements/project goals.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I need, I'll try that tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: Cool, report back on your results - I'm interested to see how it turns out in your project :)

Comment: "There isn't necessarily anything wrong with that, it's just Webpack letting you know that you're doing something funky with require - which is true :)"
That tells an important thing: "I'm not able to resolve dependencies from path in a static way". It actually dose not work if you give path in a variable, because it will not search dependencies relative to the current path.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use [multi-file namespaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files) which allow splitting code into multiple files without having to import [modules](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Here is a simplified example taken from the [TypeScript documentation on namespaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).

*Validation.ts file*

```
namespace Validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }
}
```

*LettersOnlyValidator.ts file*

```
namespace Validation {
    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like you have to keep track of files using the `/// <reference>` tag... so I don't see the difference between this and the import statement.

Comment: The triple-slash directive is optional. Taking that line out of the example above still compiles as excepted assuming both fils are included within your tsconfig.json options (example `"include": ["**/*.ts"]`).

Comment: Oh nice! I'll test it today then!

Comment: It says that `StringValidator` cannot be found